# update big table with 200mn data

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization, oracle12c

I want to update NULL TFLAG column with 0 . what would be the efficient way to update the column as the table is big.

```
stats:
-----
Size             144 GB
Num Rows         235,676,098
Number of nulls   33408624

create table ticket (hkey number , tflag number);
alter table ticket add constraint hkey_p primary key (hkey);

Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (1,1);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (2,1);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (3,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (4,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (5,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (6,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (7,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (8,1);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (9,null);
Insert into TICKET (HKEY,TFLAG) values (10,1);
Insert i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is

```
update ticket
set hflag = 0
where hflag is null;
```

The long answer is, it depends. Is the table experiencing a lot of transactions concurrently? You could add a `and rownum < 10000` (or any other number you deem appropriate) to make the transaction size smaller. Add commits between updates to not keep the records locked. But if concurrent transactions are not an issue, I would just use above update statement and let the database do its thing.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Yes transactions are happening concurrently . I want to update 33mn out of 200 mn and splitting the data and update will again take more time ,in that case I will have to run 33 update statements of 1mn in each set.Do you think that is the only option?

Comment: @kashi - no matter what you do, you are going to have to touch all 33 million rows.  It wouldn't take but a few minutes with a text editor to create 33 appropriate UPDATE and COMMIT statements in a sql text file.  Then probably not more than several minutes to execute it, In the oracle world, 33 million records, while not trivial, is really not considered to be that big.

Comment: Ok Thanks , I will give it a try .

Comment: Once you have this cleaned-up then modify your column definition to "not null default 0". This will prevent nonoccurence of this issue. You will most likely have to fix your insert as the default will not apply if the insert specifies null, also any select/update specifying hflag is null.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would probably be:

```
create table ticket_new
as
select hkey, decode( tflag, null, 0, tflag ) tflag
from ticket;
```

If you have resources, you can also do this using parallel execution.

Then rename ticket to ticket_old (as a backup )
rename ticket_new to ticket

All being good, you can now drop ticket_old.